# HTML5/jQuery Cross-Browser Responsive Images

Tags: jquery, html, web, responsive-design

I'm trying to devise a method of displaying images that resize responsively in a cross-browser-compatible manner. Using CSS3 media queries won't do because they're not supported widely. jQuery, however, affords me the ability to utilize the "data" attributes in HTML5.

This is what I have come up with. Does anyone else have good ideas? Or can offer any tweaking on this idea?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML5/jQuery Responsive Images</title>
        <style>
            body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        $(window).resize(setSize)
        $(document).ready(setSize);
        function setSize() {
            var bodywidth = $(document).width();
            var small_max = 600;
            var medium_max = 800;

            if (bodywidth > small_max && bodywidth <= medium_max) {
                $('img').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('src-800px'));
                });
            } else if (bodywidth <= small_max ) {
                $('img').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('src-600px'));
                });
            } else if (bodywidth > medium_max ) {
                $('img').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('src'));
                });
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img data-src="image.jpg" data-src-600px="image-600px.jpg" data-src-800px="image-800px.jpg" alt="Responsive image" style="width: 100%;" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you could reduce your if/then tests by half by doing: `if (bodywidth<=small_max) {...} else if (bodywidth<=medium_max) {...} else {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the img tag to display:inline would handle the responsiveness for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a series of blog posts I did on this:

http://queryj.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/responsive-images-whats-the-problem-9-2/

Basically:

1. Place image tag in a  block
2. Progressively enhance the page by adding an image based on the noscript block
3. Use media query listener to change the image when required

You need a couple of polyfills for this technique - one to be able to read the noscript tag *textContent* property and one to provide media queries and media query listeners to IE < 10.